# MySql Fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `mysql version 5.5`, i have added `Fulltext` index to products table and table type is `MyISAM`.

**My problem**: If I query with boolean mode even though I have used "+" operator, the result I am getting is in "OR" condition.

This is my query:

```
SELECT `product_name`,`product_id`, MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST ('+black +use +45000') AS score 
FROM `t2c_products_en_gb`
WHERE MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST ('+black +use +toner' in boolean mode) order by score desc;
```

Please explain what would be the problem?

Comment: In my local system, mysql version is 5.6 and table type is Innodb, the above query is working fine.

Comment: "the result i am getting is in "OR" condition." Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I have used '+' operator after all the words, so the result should contain all the three words. But if any one  word is present i am getting the result just like "OR" condition.

Comment: In the above query, +45000 should be replaced by +toner... :D

Comment: Is version is the problem? or problem in the query?

Comment: In MyIssam there is aparameter which specifies the minimum length ot the word used,[the default is 4],so use is ignored.

Comment: Thank you @Mihai . I will update the "ft_min_word_len" in mysql my.ini file. Hope it works. :)